# Tkinter entry gives me at every run () instead of value entered in the GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, user-defined-functions

Iam creating a code to make the user enter a value, but when I run it and ask me the index, the print (stableLvl) returns ().

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

root3 = tk.Tk()
root3.geometry('600x400') 
info2=tk.Label(root3,text='Enter index of last head value before initiation slug test \n',anchor='e')
info2.pack()

#Parameter
par = ('Index of stable level')

def ask_stableLvl(enter):
    global stableLvl
    stableLvl =  float(enter['Index of stable level'].get()) 
    return stableLvl
#stableLvl = int(input('Enter index of last head value before initiation slug test: '))
def fill(stableLvl):
    dic = {}
    row2 = tk.Frame(root3)
#    lab2 = tk.Label(row2, width=5, anchor='w')    
    ent2 = tk.Entry(row2)      
    row2.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.X,padx=2,pady=2)
#    lab2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    ent2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=tk.NO,fill=tk.X)
    dic[stableLvl] = ent2
    return dic
save_button1 = tk.Button(root3)
save_button1.configure(text='Save', command=lambda: ask_stableLvl)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ent2 = fill(stableLvl)


save_button1.pack()
root3.mainloop()
print(stableLvl)
```

The result gives me all the time () instead of the value entered in the GUI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter Entry always returning empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773536/tkinter-entry-always-returning-empty-string)

Comment: in stableLvl =  float(enter['Index of stable level'].get()), 
enter needs a value, in lamda you are invoking the function without passing its respective parameter